# How to remove the collection name from the mongoose find return?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, router

I am trying to return the values of a collection in MongoDB in Node.js using Express.js + Mongoose. The client that is going to consume that is expecting the data in a different format than mine. The returned data should be like that:

> [{
>       "userId": 1,
>       "id": 1,
>       "title": "some title",
>       "body": "some body"
>     },{
>       "userId": 1,
>       "id": 2,
>       "title": "another title",
>       "body": "another body"
>     }, ...

However, the json returned by my service have the collection name (in my example, flavors) as the first element in the json, like that:

> {"flavors":[{"_id":"5b818da7fb6fc0183b40ea50","name":"a name","kind":"a kind"},{"_id":"5b818dd8fb6fc0183b40ea5b","name":"another name","kind":"another kind"},...

That's my code:

```
...
import Flavor from "../models/flavors";
...
const router = express.Router();

router.options("/", (req, res) => {
  Flavor.find().then(result => {
     res.json({ result });
  }).catch((err) => {
     res.status(500).json({ success: false, msg: `Something went wrong. ${err}` });
  });
});
```

Here the model in models/flavors:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";
const schema = new Schema(
{
        name: String,
        kind: String,
 });

export default mongoose.model("flavors", schema);
```

So, how do I get rid of this flavors (the collection name) in the get result?

Comment: what is MyModel? Is it a valid mongoose model? Can you share your model class

Comment: Where does `collection_name` come from, why is it there in the first place? Any way, you need to use `toObject` (`lean`) or `toJSON` to get clean object for JSON response.

Comment: to clarify, I added the model and changed the collection_name to the real name of the model.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. The error is in the curly braces inside the res.json, in this part of the code:

```
router.options("/", (req, res) => { 
    Flavor.find().then(result => {
        res.json({ result });
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, msg: `Something wrong. ${err}`    });});});`
```

So, if it is used in this way:

```
res.json({ result });
```

the collection name from mongo/mongoose will show first. When I change to this way:

```
res.json(result);
```

the collection name goes away.